# asp.net Core "The debug profile 'Test' has requested a web browser to be launched, but a URL was not specified"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I removed the `iis express` settings from the `launchsettings json` file in asp.net core project but when i tried launching the application...the following error occurred.."The debug profile `'test'` has requested a web browser to be launched, but a URL was not specified. But google chrome was selected as the default browser for launching. Please help me out
my `launchsettings json` file code is attached below

```
{

  "profiles": {

    "test": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,

      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you share the current `launchsetting.json`? For error, it complains `TestMVc`, but, there is no such node in your shared file. Trun to project properties, and select `Debug tab` to check the right profile settings.

Comment: its actually test i have checked and updated above

Comment: I fail to reproduce your issue by copying your current test profile to my project. Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Having the same issue with a Asp.Net non core (https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2670) project. I can run it from the profile configured for "IISExpress" but it just hangs, I get the same error as you when running the profile configured for "Project"

Comment: @Bronumski i was unable to solve this problem but when i made new project i did not face any issue you may also try this

Answer (score 0):

Likely what's occurring is a host settings file, or a call to using UseUrls in your application entry point, is overriding the settings of launchSettings. Check to see if you have anything within appsettings.development.json or appsettings.local.json, such as a bad "Urls" setting which could be causing this behavior.

If none of the above helps, perhaps try to delete your "vs" and "bin" folders.